# Vertical scroll in card doesn't go all the way

Tags: html, css, scroll

I am trying to create a results page where each result is in a card, and inside the card, there are nested information such as menu and name. I want the menu part to be vertically scrollable, but for some reason, the last card doesn't scroll all the way down. I don't want the card to be scrollable, just the menu part.

**HTML:**

```
    <div class="results">
        <div class="shadow p-4 mb-6 rounded result ">
            <p class='rest-title'>McDonalds</p>
            <p class="rest-address">401 College Ave, Ithaca, NY 14850</p>
            <div class="item-container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-10">
                        <p class="item-name">Filet O Fish</p>
                        <p class="item-des">Lightly breaded and fried white fish served on a brioche with romaine
                            lettuce and pickles</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-2 price">
                        <i class="fa fa-usd fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        <p class="item-price">5.00</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <hr class="solid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-10">
                        <p class="item-name">Filet O Fish</p>
                        <p class="item-des">Lightly breaded and fried white fish served on a brioche with romaine
                            lettuce and pickles</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-2 price">
                        <i class="fa fa-usd fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        <p class="item-price">5.00</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <hr class="solid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-10">
                        <p class="item-name">Filet O Fish</p>
                        <p class="item-des">Lightly breaded and fried white fish served on a brioche with romaine
                            lettuce and pickles</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-2 price">
                        <i class="fa fa-usd fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        <p class="item-price">5.00</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <hr class="solid">
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="shadow p-4 mb-6 rounded result">
            <p class='rest-title'>McDonalds</p>
            <p class="rest-address">401 College Ave, Ithaca, NY 14850</p>
            <div class="item-container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-10">
                        <p class="item-name">Filet O Fish</p>
                        <p class="item-des">Lightly breaded and fried white fish served on a brioche with romaine
                            lettuce and pickles</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-2 price">
                        <i class="fa fa-usd fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        <p class="item-price">5.00</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <hr class="solid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-10">
                        <p class="item-name">Filet O Fish</p>
                        <p class="item-des">Lightly breaded and fried white fish served on a brioche with romaine
                            lettuce and pickles</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-2 price">
                        <i class="fa fa-usd fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        <p class="item-price">5.00</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <hr class="solid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-10">
                        <p class="item-name">Filet O Fish</p>
                        <p class="item-des">Lightly breaded and fried white fish served on a brioche with romaine
                            lettuce and pickles</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-2 price">
                        <i class="fa fa-usd fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        <p class="item-price">5.00</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <hr class="solid">
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="shadow p-4 mb-6 rounded result">
            <p class='rest-title'>McDonalds</p>
            <p class="rest-address">401 College Ave, Ithaca, NY 14850</p>
            <div class="item-container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-10">
                        <p class="item-name">Filet O Fish</p>
                        <p class="item-des">Lightly breaded and fried white fish served on a brioche with romaine
                            lettuce and pickles</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-2 price">
                        <i class="fa fa-usd fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        <p class="item-price">5.00</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <hr class="solid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-10">
                        <p class="item-name">Filet O Fish</p>
                        <p class="item-des">Lightly breaded and fried white fish served on a brioche with romaine
                            lettuce and pickles</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-2 price">
                        <i class="fa fa-usd fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        <p class="item-price">5.00</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <hr class="solid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-10">
                        <p class="item-name">Filet O Fish</p>
                        <p class="item-des">Lightly breaded and fried white fish served on a brioche with romaine
                            lettuce and pickles</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-2 price">
                        <i class="fa fa-usd fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        <p class="item-price">5.00</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.result {
 overflow: hidden;
 max-height: 350px;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
 background-color: white;
}
enter code here
.rest-title {
 font-size: 2rem;
 font-weight: 700;
 margin-bottom: 0px
}

.rest-address {
 font-family: 'Open Sans';
 font-size:14px
}

.item-container {
 overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

[image: Example of issue]

Comment: Do you want to scroll in x-asis or y-asis? I am able to scroll with your code in y-asis.

Comment: y axis, but for me, it doesn't scroll all the way down, as shown in the picture. Part of it cuts off

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In every group of item-containers, the last divs are crushing because you set max-height for them.

In the `.result` class, you're setting;

```
max-height:350px 
overflow: hidden
```

Because of these two, you cannot fully see the last items of `.item-container` class. So, if you will change the overflow attribute like `overflow-y: scroll`, it should solve your problem. With this solution, you will be able to scroll in all results.

If you want to scroll in `.item-containter` only; you should set a max-height and keep the  `overflow-y:scroll`.